# Firebase Functions V2 - data.after.ref is undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I implemented a onDocumentUpdated function in firebase. I copied the exact same code from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#node.js_11). When the function is triggered im getting the error below somehow, can anyone help me with this one ?
The error is thrown in when calling the data.after.red.set method.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')

```
import { onDocumentUpdated } from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";

exports.countnamechanges = onDocumentUpdated('users/{userId}', (event) => {
  // Retrieve the current and previous value
  const data = event.data.after.data();
  const previousData = event.data.before.data();

  // We'll only update if the name has changed.
  // This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
  if (data.name == previousData.name) {
    return null;
  }

  // Retrieve the current count of name changes
  let count = data.name_change_count;
  if (!count) {
    count = 0;
  }

  // Then return a promise of a set operation to update the count
  return data.after.ref.set({
    name_change_count: count + 1
  }, {merge: true});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You first declare `const data = event.data.after.data();` and then do `return data.after.ref.set({})` which cannot work since `data` is a JS Object which does not have an `after` property (unless you have an `after` field in your doc...).

You should do `return event.data.after.ref.set({...})`.

Comment: Hey @thiemo, did you have time to look at the proposed answer?